# setcookie makes cookie but then it immediately disappears in Chrome on Windows and OS X

Tags: php, google-chrome, setcookie

So I have a line in php that sets a cookie and it has been working for a while now, but, this week chrome does not want to keep the cookie. The cookie gets added and when I hit refresh in the chrome dev tools it disappears.

Chrome for both Windows and OS X are doing the same thing. Chrome started doing this out of the blue. Firefox on Windows and OS X and safari on OS X do not have the issue.

I am using a date far enough in advance that its not an expiry issue.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Currently running:

```
setcookie('key', $value, time()+3600, '/');
```

Was running:

```
setcookie('key', $value, 2000000000, '/');
```

Comment: Please, add `setcookie` function code here.

Comment: @Pinal, [`setcookie` is provided by PHP](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Im sorry, I don't understand; I posted the code I am using in my question.

Comment: Possibly a time zone issue?

Comment: Well the "2000000000" provided makes the expiry date around 2033 so I am not sure how the time zone would be an issue. Everything was working fine in Chrome and then a few hours later I started running into the issue. I check the version and it did not appear to be updated or anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849013/setcookie-does-not-set-cookie-in-google-chrome?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

based on documentation expire in  Unix timestamp 
check this link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

best, set expire 0 or calculate no more of year 2038

```
setcookie("keyCookie", $value, 0);
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue. First off the cookie now shows that it expires session which is not the desired effect. The cookie needs to stay in place and secondly, when I refresh the dev tools the cookie immediately disappears.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I may have solved the issue of the cookie disappearing. I'm not sure it's a real fix but at least it is not disappearing now.

Here is how the code looks:

```
setcookie('key', $value, 2000000000, '/', 'www.site.com');
```

Now the only difference between the two cookies in the dev tools is a preceding period in the domain path. I don't know why this would be causing a problem for Chrome.

Not Persistant:

```
key | value | www.site.com | / | Wed, 18 May 2033 03:33:19 GMT | 100
```

Persistant:

```
key | value | .www.site.com | / | Wed, 18 May 2033 03:33:19 GMT | 100
```