# Cookie value issue on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, header, setcookie

I have an issue with the value of a cookie, this issue happens only whenusing Chrome but not on Firefox or IE.

I have the following code, which runs every time the user logs in:

```
function randomUserKey($length)
{
    $random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
    $key = bin2hex($random);

    return $key;
}

/*SET COOKIE*/
$UserKey= randomUserKey(32);

$expiration= time() + 365*24*3600;

setcookie('CookieID', $UserKey, $expiration, NULL, NULL);

//testing the value of $UserKey in the console              
echo'<script type="text/javascript">console.log("'.$UserKey.'");</script>';
/************/
```

Now, if I compare the value of `$UserKey` in the console to the value of the cookie in the Response Headers it as a value of X in FF and IE. Which is what I want.
But on Chrome, the value in the console is X, and the value in the Response Header is Y. And if I look at the Request Header, the cookie as the correct value: X.
On FF or IE, the cookie in the Request Header as the value of the previously created cookie (previous connexion of the user). This is the correct behaviour, the one I am expecting. User comes with a cookie > I check the value > It's verified > user is logged in and gets a new cookie.

So I definitely have a problem on Chrome, but I can't figure out where it is coming from.

Thank you for any help you can give, I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849013/setcookie-does-not-set-cookie-in-google-chrome
Tried out with once this Procedure.

Comment: I looked at the topic but what do you mean? I should specify that I am not on localhost and I have no problem with the cookie expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine found the answer here: [What to do with chrome sending extra requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460661/what-to-do-with-chrome-sending-extra-requests)

Chrome is sending extra requests, apparently for surfing speed purpose.
My problem was coming from this particular html tag:
`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href=""/>`
The empty href was the issue. I just deleted the tag, but I guess putting a valid image url works just as well.